# SQL : Group By on range of dynamic values

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, range

This is similar to some other questions here, but those use a CASE which I cannot. This is on Oracle, and I will be running the query from an excel sheet. (And by the way these do not support WITH, which makes life much harder)

I have a range of dates in one big table - like 1/3/2011, 4/5/2012, 7/1/2013, 9/1/2013.....
Then I have another table with hours worked by employees on certain dates. So what I need to do is get a sum of number of hours worked by each employee in each intervening time period. So the tables are like

```
Dates
1-May-2011
5-Aug-2011 
4-Apr-2012
....
```

and another

```
Employee   Hours   Date
Sam        4       1-Jan-2011
Sam        7       5-Jan-2011
Mary       12      7-Jan-2012
Mary       5       12-Dec-2013
......
```

so the result should be

```
Employee  Hours   In Date Range Till
Sam       11      1-May-2011
Sam       0       5-Aug-2011
Sam       0       4-Apr-2012
Mary      0       1-May-2011
Mary      0       5-Aug-2011
Mary      12      4-Apr-2012
....
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this please?

Comment: You have an error in your desired result. An a question: any specific implementation/flavor/server?

Comment: if it's on Oracle, shouldn't it be tagged?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the error.

Comment: Sam shouldn't be 4 on 5-aug-2011

Comment: "And by the way these do not support WITH, which makes life much harder" - Could you access a view using WITH?

Comment: With would be to create a 'temporary table'. Excel is not supporting With

Comment: Also, I can't create views

Comment: The intentions were clear enough without expending the date range column, but the value still needs to be 0 (Sam's last hours were on 5-Jan-2011, before 1-may-2011)

Comment: Ouch, you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Oracle SQL and it's abilities/limitations, but since you asked for pointers, here's my take:
Join the tables (INNER JOIN) with the join rule being `EmployeeHours.Date < Dates.Dates`. Then `GROUP BY Employee, Dates.Dates` and select the grouping columns + SUM(Hours). What you'd end up with (Using your sample data) is:

```
Employee |   Dates     |  Hours
Sam      | 1-May-2011  |   11
Sam      | 5-Aug-2011  |   11
Sam      | 4-Apr-2012  |   11
Mary     | 1-May-2011  |   0
Mary     | 5-Aug-2011  |   0
Mary     | 4-Apr-2012  |   12
```

With other (more complex) data, there will be more "interesting" results, but basically each row contains total hours up to that point.

You could then use that as an input to an outer query to find `MAX(Hours)` for all rows where `Dates < currentDates` and subtract that from your result.

Again, this is not a complete answer, but it's a direction that should work.